# How to make a circle with SVG Path tag, using Arc attributes

Tags: svg

Recently, I started studying SVG to build some Pie Charts. Although I'm well aware that the world is full of ready-to-use libraries, my needs required that I implemented myself the SVG writter to build my graphs. Later on, those graphs are converted to PNG and shipped as email body (while most libraries great for this are written in JS and emails cannot run JS for security reasons).

Anyway, now that my work is practically done and everything works great, I stumbled upon something I did not test while writing the library: When you have only 1 data that takes 100% of the Pie Chart.

As you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/vivikosaga/edit?html,output), when you have a **Path** defining the starting point and the ending point as the same, the result is just **nothing**, even though I defined the Arc flag that refers to going the long path from start to end. I really don't want to rework my library in order to make a plain **circle** when the data represents 100% of the total. Do I have any viable solution with **path** tag only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://complexdan.com/svg-circleellipse-to-path-converter/) page might help you work out how to do it?

Comment: @RobertLongson wouldn't that be practically the same as using the circle? My problem lies in the need of adding a conditional structure to the "addSlice" function that verifies if the slice represents 100% of the pie. To make 2 arcs, I'd need to verify condition, as well as making a circle instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson so the truth is, it is working as it's suppose to work. Arcs with starting and ending points overlapping will not present any data?